# Strategy game - weird resource bug

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$time_current = time();
$User = $con->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
$UserInfo = $User->fetch_object();

if($UserInfo->Wood == "") {
$con->query("UPDATE players SET Wood='100'");
} elseif($UserInfo->Stone == "") {
$con->query("UPDATE players SET Stone='100'");
} elseif($UserInfo->Gold == "") {
$con->query("UPDATE players SET Gold='100'");
}

if((time() - $UserInfo->LastGivenWood) >= 10) {

$wood_to_give = 20;
$time = 10;
$last_given = $UserInfo->LastGivenWood;
$added_wood = ceil(($time_current-$last_given )/$time) * $wood_to_give;
echo $added_wood."<br>";
echo $last_given."<br>";
echo $time."<br>"; 
echo $wood_to_give."<br>";
$con->query("UPDATE players SET Wood=Wood+$added_wood WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");


}
if((time() - $UserInfo->LastGivenStone) >= 10) {

$stone_to_give = 20;
$time = 10;
$last_given = $UserInfo->LastGivenStone;
$added_stone = ceil(($time_current-$last_given)/$time) * $stone_to_give;
$con->query("UPDATE players SET Stone=Stone+$added_stone WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");


    }

    if (isset($added_wood) && $added_wood>0) $con->query("UPDATE players SET LastGivenWood=$time_current WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");

    if (isset($added_stone) && $added_stone>0) $con->query("UPDATE players SET LastGivenStone=$time_current WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
```

For some very weird reason, `$added_stone` is a number similar to `2,757,953,800` THE FIRST time the resources is given (straight after the user logs in for the first time) I tried echoing it again AFTER the first receiveal of the resources. The second time it was just as it should be (20)

So all my of resources get set to a number similar to `2,757,953,800`, does anyone know how to fix this

**EDIT:** ALSO, by `$last_given` I meant `$added_wood` and `$added_stone` (they both behave the same) Sorry.

Comment: I don't see $last_added anywhere.

Comment: Have you meant `$last_given` instead of `$last_added`?

Comment: sorry I couldn't get what do you want?

Comment: Given that you compare `$last_given` with `time()` in your conditionals, are you actually displaying the value as-is, or are you doing some arithmetic with `time()` on it first? Might it be that it really has a default value of zero?

Comment: Im calculating if the difference between the current time and last given time is 10 seconds, also calculate all of the expirations. So for example if the user goes offline for 2 hours then comes back he will get the money for 2 hours, even if he was offline during that period of time.

Comment: ALSO, by `$last_given` I meant `$added_wood` and `$added_stone` (they both behave the same) Sorry.

Comment: I think I saw another bug in your code. the first  `if-else` what is it for?

Comment: by default the mysql columns for wood, stone and gold are empty.

Comment: I know but if more than one be empty just first will filled

Comment: and also I still don't know whats your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$UserInfo->LastGivenWood` defaults to zero.

When you first hit this conditional, it triggers because `time() >= 10`:

```
if((time() - $UserInfo->LastGivenWood) >= 10) {
```

Then you  wood to the player's resource storage based on the time since the zero timestamp (0 is the Unix Epoch, the beginning of 1970 -- that's why it ends up being quite a bit of wood):

```
  $last_given = $UserInfo->LastGivenWood;
  $added_wood = ceil(($time_current-$last_given )/$time) * $wood_to_give;
```

Comment: @Will The best way would probably be to initialize `LastGivenWood` to the current time when the UserInfo object is created in the database. Alternately you can specifically check for zero, and set the timestamp to the current time without giving out any resources.